# Add padding to sunburst layout d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

Following [this example](https://codepen.io/stopyransky/pen/EXdrOo) I am creating a sunburst diagram. I would like to add a bit of padding between each node. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var sunburstLayout = d3.partition();

var radius = 100;
sunburstLayout.size([2*Math.PI, radius]);
//sunburstLayout.padding(2);

var arc= d3.arc()
.startAngle( function(d) { return d.x0 })
.endAngle(   function(d) { return d.x1 })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return d.y0 })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return d.y1 })

root.sum(d  => d.value);
...
```

which produces this:

[image]

Now when adding:

```
sunburstLayout.padding(2);
```

The layout is messed up.

[image]

```
sunburstLayout.padding(1);
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to keep the layout correct while being able to add padding to each node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you just found a limitation of this `padding` method. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/src/partition.js#L21)...

```
function positionNode(dy, n) {
    return function(node) {
        if (node.children) {
            treemapDice(node, node.x0, dy * (node.depth + 1) / n, node.x1, dy * (node.depth + 2) / n);
        }
        var x0 = node.x0,
            y0 = node.y0,
            x1 = node.x1 - padding,
            y1 = node.y1 - padding;
        if (x1 < x0) x0 = x1 = (x0 + x1) / 2;
        if (y1 < y0) y0 = y1 = (y0 + y1) / 2;
        node.x0 = x0;
        node.y0 = y0;
        node.x1 = x1;
        node.y1 = y1;
    };
}
```

... you'll see that it works for linear distances, but it doesn't work for radial layouts, where `x` and `y` don't represent a cartesian coordinate. Therefore, it can be used for icicles, but nor for sunbursts.

A quick and dirty workaround is changing the arc generator instead, using `padAngle` and adding the linear value in both `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` (in `innerRadius` you add the value, and in `outerRadius` you subtract the value). That gives us:

[image]

This is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBWMKm?editors=0010